# Tweedie GLM and model selection

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-selection, model, tweedie-distribution

I have run a tweedie glm since my data is zero skewed. How can I use Akaike weights and evidence ratio to choose from models the better one. Please guide. I had earlier run models with glm but with binomial distribution. That time I could use the aictab command to get the Akaike weights and evidence ratio. However, now the same table shows NA. If I need to do model selection for tweedies distribution how do I go about it. I would be using the AIC values and not AICc since $n/K$ ratio is $>40$.

Comment: My question has been resolved. I have extracted AIC values of my tweedie models with AICtweedie command. Also for calculating Akaike weights, I have used the qPCR package.

Comment: Also, the ```dredge``` function of ```MuMIn``` package can help a lot with model selection of objects cpglm and cpglmm.